# change different element on .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, click

I'm not sure, how to use .click in the right way.

I looked at the manual (http://api.jquery.com/click/) but could not find the answer for my problem:

I'm generating an div structure with JS like this:

```
<div>
   <img id='img_1' src="click.gif">
</div>
<div id='content_1'> Text</div>
```

Lots of those blocks are generated with the following function. At the end, each image gets an click event to change the css of the related text: click on img_1 changes css on content_1.
I try this code (simplified version):

```
$.each(data, function(selector,content) {
     id=prepare(selector);
     $('#boxDiv').append('    <div>\
                               <img id="img_'+id+'" src="click.gif">\
                             </div>\
                             <div id="content_'+id+'"> Text</div>');
     $('#img_'+id).click(function(a) {
                         $('#content_'+id).css('height','100px');});
});
```

But this code does not work as I exacted.

Every `'img_'+id` Element gets his related click event (so far, so god)
But the function does not change the css of the related `'content_'+id`! All the time, the last content element is changed.
It looks like, that the .click call-back function does not get the `id`at the time of adding click event, but at the time of execution the callback function. At this time, the `id` is (of course) always the last element.

So the question is, how to bring the current (related) `id` inside the .click -callback function?

//Update: I'm not sure, if using live() could help in this case: i tried this, without any success.
The problem is not an missing click event. The Problem is, that at every click, the callback-function is fired by using the last `id`.
Example.
The generated content looks like this:

```
<div>
   <img id='img_1' src="click.gif">
</div>
<div id='content_1'> Text</div>
<div>
   <img id='img_2' src="click.gif">
</div>
<div id='content_2'> Text</div>
<div>
   <img id='img_3' src="click.gif">
</div>
<div id='content_3'> Text</div>
```

The JS code binds one click event to `img_1`, one click event to `img_2` and one click event to `img_3`.
I changed the content of the callback function to:

```
$('#expand_'+id).live('click',function() {console.info(id);});
```

SO i see the content of ID: by clicking `img_1` or `img_2` id is 3. Probably because, 3 is the last value for the each loop. So how can i get the related `id` inside the call-back?

Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: You're missing the `#` from your selector in the click event handler.

Comment: thank you, i will edit this - but this is only a typo by writing this simplified question

Comment: Your code seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/Bqfye/

Comment: Are you sure you are using `$.each`? Your problem would make sense if you'd use a normal `for` loop. Again, your code works fine in my little example. Maybe you can setup a more complete http://jsfiddle.net/ yourself, which reproduces the problem.

Comment: yes, i use $.each. so the problem seams to located in some code details, which i have changed at this simplified example to give you a better overview. I have updated the code to bring at a bit more to the real version... Maybe it's a problem by not using the original key `selector`?! I have modify this selector to use this content as an HTLM id

Comment: @Felix Kling  god idea, i will try a more complete code at jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Felix Kling i think, that's it: http://jsfiddle.net/Bqfye/5/ the changing of ID.  Hmmm.. how could i handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem [in your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bqfye/5/) (and your updated code):

You forgot to put `var`in front of `id`, which makes it global. All event handlers reference the same `id` and its value is the one from the last iteration.

Declare it as

```
var id = ....;
```

to make it local.

---

That said, I would use jQuery to create all the elements:

```
$.each(data, function(selector,content) {
     var id = selector;

     var $img = $('<span />', {
         id: 'img_' + id,
         text: 'click'
     }).click(function() {
          $('#content_'+id).css('height','100px');
     });

     var $div = $('<div />', {
         id: 'content_' + id,
         text: 'Text'
     });

     $('<div />').append($img).append($div).appendTo('#boxDiv');
});
```

There are also other ways to find the `#content_X` elements. In your structure, this element is always the next sibling of the parent of the image. So instead searching for the element with this ID, inside the event handler, you could do:

```
$(this).parent().next().css(...);
```

Or even bind the event handler to the parent `div` instead directly to the image.

Comment: Oh jeah! that's it! Thank you so much. Thank you also for investigation this problem at all! I spend in this hours! I know, that parent&next is an option, but selecting by id seams a bit more "robust" - not sure, how often the <div> structure will be changed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean

```
$.each(data, function(id,content) {
     $('#boxDiv').append('    <div>\
                               <img id="img_'+id+'" src="click.gif">\
                             </div>\
                             <div id="content_'+id+'"> Text</div>');
     $('#img_'+id).click, function(a) {
                         $('#content_'+id).css('height','100px');
     });
});
```

? There were two missing # before ID

Comment: You only need `.live()` when you want to bind event handlers to elements that don't exist yet. In this example, The elemetn `#img_X` *does* exist (it was just created and appended).

Comment: @genesis φ ...as  Felix Kling said. Please take a look to my edited question

Comment: @genesis φ yes, i changed .click to .live

Comment: Copying is not an option, because my code is much more different. I found the solution, but: thank you, for spending time to my question

Answer (score 0):

The click event handler will have access to the `id` (and `content`) variable, as it's defined in the parent function. In JavaScript, inner functions have access to all the variables of the function in which they are defined.

The problem is simply that you are missing the `#` ID selector from a couple of your jQuery selector string:

```
$('#boxDiv').append('...');
//some code removed
$('#content_' + id).css('height', '100px');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the .click call-back function, you should use the .live call-back [function](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Quoting the jquery docs:

"Description: Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the **future**."

Try this:

```
$.each(data, function(id,content) {
 $('boxDiv').append('    <div>\
                           <img id="img_'+id+'" src="click.gif">\
                         </div>\
                         <div id="content_'+id+'"> Text</div>');
 $('#img_'+id).live('click', function() {
                     $('content_'+id).css('height','100px');});
});
```

Comment: .live does not help. please take a look at my edited question an the commend from Felix Kling at the answer from genesis φ